# Extending rank() "Olympic Style"

Tags: r

In the olympics, if two people are tied for silver - they don't give out a bronze medal.

Here's a sample of the kind of data I'm working with:

```
x <- c(0.64, 0.64, 0.63, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 0.61, 0.6, 0.6, 0.58)
```

I'd like to create a ranking function that outputs like so:

```
rank.fun(x) 
1 1 3 4 4 4 7 8 8 10
```

I've tried messing around with `findInterval`, `rank`, `floor`, `ceiling` but none of them seem to provide the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this: 
    `rank(-x, ties.method="min")`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you can do this with `rank`:

```
> rank(-x, ties="min")
 [1]  1  1  3  4  4  4  7  8  8 10
```

Comment: The answer is so simple. Sigh.

Comment: Maybe, but it's often hard to see the simple solution when it doesn't occur to you immediately.